# Android O - How to draw over the status bar as a system app?

Tags: android, system, android-8.0-oreo, status

I know that TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR, TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY, TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT etc were deprecated in Android O, which basically banned regular apps from being able to draw over critical system components(like the status bar).
However, in the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR) they say:

> **This constant was deprecated in API level 26.**
>   for non-system apps. Use **TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY** instead.

---

> was deprecated ... for non-system apps

So, from what I understand you can still use TYPE_SYSTEM_[whatever] in some way IF you are developing as a system app but I can't find any link to help me with that.
My app is signed with the same key as the OS on the device I'm deploying it on, so it's a system app.

Does anyone know if there is a way?